# Is an electric heat gun powerful enough to help aid in metalwork?

Tags: metal, steel, aluminum

I've seen videos where metalworkers will heat up some sheet metal with a blow torch to make it more malleable. Could this be done with an electric heat gun (just working with ~1 to 2mm thick steel and aluminium)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric heat gun of the typical 1500 or 1750 Watts would not be particularly capable of heating the metal up to the red temperature where it gets more malleable. Especially for metal that was 1 or 2 mm thick. The metal acts too much like a heatsink.

Comment: Sorry should of been more clearer - I'm talking about annealing, similar to on this video https://youtu.be/tlbDuuEH-Us?t=5m30s